# PHP array count off by 1

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array for each year being returned that holds all of the months and the months blog entries. I am trying to return the total count of blogs for the entire year. However, the number is one off every time. There should be a total of 6, but returns 5.

**Array**

```
array (size=2)
  '04' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '5' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=36)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '04' (length=2)
          'day' => string '30' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'Apr. 30, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=86)
  '05' => 
    array (size=5)
      0 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '4' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=56)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '05' (length=2)
          'day' => string '14' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'May. 14, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=96)
      1 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '7' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=58)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '05' (length=2)
          'day' => string '15' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'May. 15, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=105)
      2 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '8' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=45)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '05' (length=2)
          'day' => string '15' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'May. 15, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=95)
      3 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '9' (length=1)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=52)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '05' (length=2)
          'day' => string '15' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'May. 15, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=98)
      4 => 
        array (size=7)
          'entry_id' => string '10' (length=2)
          'title' => string 'Post Title' (length=33)
          'year' => string '2015' (length=4)
          'month' => string '05' (length=2)
          'day' => string '15' (length=2)
          'date' => string 'May. 15, 2015' (length=13)
          'link' => string 'www.brand.com/blog/title' (length=83)
```

**Loop**

```
    $year_count  = 0;

    foreach($year_data as $year_posts) {

       $year_count += count($year_posts);
    }

    echo $year_count;
```

print_r of $year_posts

```
     Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 6
                [title] => Blog Title 
                [year] => 2014
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 14
                [date] => May. 14, 2014
                [link] => blog link
            )

    )


   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 5
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 04
                [day] => 30
                [date] => Apr. 30, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

    )


    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 4
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 14
                [date] => May. 14, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 7
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 15
                [date] => May. 15, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 8
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 15
                [date] => May. 15, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 9
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 15
                [date] => May. 15, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [entry_id] => 10
                [title] => Blog Title
                [year] => 2015
                [month] => 05
                [day] => 15
                [date] => May. 15, 2015
                [link] => blog-url
            )

    )
```

Comment: why `$year_count  = 0;` is inside the loop?

Comment: @Leggendario I thought I needed to set a base for the count.

Comment: in this way `$year_count` will be `$year_count == count($year_posts)`. You need to put it outside.

Comment: This way first it's set to 1 (size of first sub-array), then 0, then 5 (second sub-array)

Comment: @Miura-shi base count is required, but `$year_count = 0;` should be outside of foreach loop.

Comment: @cosmoo Thanks, I set them outside and I am still getting 5 instead of 6.

Comment: $year_count += count($year_posts);

Comment: @splash58 I corrected it, but now it says there's 7 instead of 6?

Comment: 4=> 1 and 5 => 5. must be 6. isn't it?

Comment: @Miura-shi can you place a  `print_r($year_posts)` before `$year_count += count($year_posts);` and share the output with us?

Comment: @Miura-shi your program is right... your observation is wrong. 7 is the right answer, its 03=>1 + 04=>1 + 05=>5 = total=>7

Comment: @cosmoo Yes, i've added it to the post.

Comment: there are 7 entries. I don't know where you take id=6 :)

Comment: @Miura-shi seems to be 7 posts. Are you only trying to get 2015 posts?

Comment: @cosmoo Right, collectively there is 7 total posts, but I am trying to check individually for each year.

Comment: add the condition to sum or make year_count[year]

Comment: @Miura-shi you need a condition otherwise the loop will give you a count for every post.

Comment: @Miura-shi the question itself contradicts. In the first var_dump, there is no entry_id = 6. but later when you printed the array, you have entry_id = 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP has some robust [array functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that are worth familiarizing yourself with. There's often an easier alternative to single-line loops of this sort.

```
$post_count = array_sum(array_map('count', $year_data));
```

Comment: Very clean approach. This worked beautifully, thanks!